# Consumer-Producer problem

Tags: c

I am having a problem with my Consumer, producer program, it seems to load, but returns a segmentation error. I have tried everything to fix it but still failing!! Will be greatful for any assistance.
Note; The code is really much, semaphore.h code is within, if anyone wishes to test. and the rest of the code is as is here. Am runing this on a Unix machine.

```
      //----------------SEMOPHORE.H--------------------------
    /*********************** semaphore.h ****************************/
    #define SEM_NAME "semaphore.h",'a'
    #define SEM_MAX   3
    #define FREE      0
    #define DATA      1
    #define ROOM      2
    #define S_WAIT   -1
    #define S_SIGNAL  1
    #define NO_EVENT -1

    int sem_config(int, int);
    int sem_wait(int, int);
    int sem_signal(int, int);

    //----------------Producer-----------------------
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include"semaphore.h"
    #include"shbuf.h"
    # include <string.h>  
    # include "shbuf.h"  

    void myadd();  

    main()
    {
        sem_config(DATA, FREE);
        myadd();
        sem_signal(DATA,S_SIGNAL);
        return 0;
    }
    void myadd()  
     {  
       char str[80];  
       char discard;  
       printf("you can type a message for the producer."\n);  
       printf("Producing message : ");  
       scanf("%s%c", str, &discard);  
       q_add(strlen(str) , str);  
     }  
    //---------------------------CONSUMER---------------------------
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include"semaphore.h"
    #include"shbuf.h"

    # include <string.h>  
    # include "shbuf.h"  

    void myremove(); 

    main()
    {
    sem_wait(DATA, S_WAIT);
    myremove();
    sem_signal(DATA,S_SIGNAL);

    return 0;
    }

    void myremove()  
     {  
       char str[80];  
       if(q_items() > 0)  
       {  
         q_remove(1 , str);  
         str[1] = 0;  
         printf("%s\n", str);  
       }  
     } 
    //-------------------------------SEMAPHORE.C--------------------------------------
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/ipc.h>
    #include <sys/sem.h>
    #include "semaphore.h"

    static  int sem_id;

    static  union semun 
        {
            int val; /* value for SETVAL */
            struct semid_ds *buf; /* buffer for IPC_STAT & IPC_SET */
            ushort array[1]; /* array for GETALL & SETALL, used in setting or retrieving all semaphorevalues in a set.*/
        } sem_attr;

    static  struct sembuf asem[1];
    static  key_t s_key; //key for shared memory

    int sem_config(int event, int init_val)
     {
        int x;
        s_key = ftok(SEM_NAME); //key for semaphore
        //create a semaphore for process synchronization
        if ( -1 == (sem_id = semget(s_key, SEM_MAX, 0666|IPC_CREAT ) ))
        {
            perror("semget");
            return -1;
        }
        if ( event == NO_EVENT )
            return 0;   /*locate semaphore only*/
        //set initial value of semaphore
        sem_attr.val = init_val;
        if ( -1 == semctl(sem_id, event, SETVAL, sem_attr ) )
        {
            perror("semctl SETVAL");
            return -1;
        }
        if ( -1 == ( x = semctl(sem_id, event, GETVAL, sem_attr ) ) )
        {
            perror("semctl GETVAL");
            return -1;
        }
        assert( x == init_val );
        return 0;
     }

    int sem_wait(int event, int nwaits)
    {
        asem[0].sem_num = event;
        asem[0].sem_op = nwaits * S_WAIT;
        asem[0].sem_flg = 0;
        if ( event == NO_EVENT )    /*remove semaphore set*/
            if ( -1 == semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, sem_attr ) )
            {
                perror("semctl IPC_RMID");
                return -1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        if ( -1 == semop(sem_id, asem, 1 ) )
        {
            perror("semop");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int sem_signal(int event, int nsignals)
     {
        asem[0].sem_num = event;
        asem[0].sem_op = nsignals * S_SIGNAL;
        asem[0].sem_flg = 0;
        if ( event == NO_EVENT )
            if ( -1 == semctl(sem_id, 0, IPC_RMID, sem_attr ) )
            {
                perror("semctl IPC_RMID");
                return -1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        if ( -1 == semop(sem_id, asem, 1 ) )
        {
            perror("semop");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Could you explain what in particular is failing?

Comment: Where are you getting the fault? Can you try inserting `printf` in your code and see where it fails? Also, make sure you do not try to write more than 79 characters in your `str`.

Comment: when I run the test file, two terminals open, consumer comes with a segmentation falult. and when I type some info into producer, segmentation fault again. Looks like I am not dealing with the memory pretty well. I cant figure our where the fauls is really

Answer (score 3):

In general, the best way to debug segmentation faults is by compiling with the `-g` flag and running in a debugger like gdb.  It will tell you exactly where it is crashing and let you print out the values of variables to tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with debugging symbols.  If you're using `gcc` then use the `-g3` flag for the most symbols.  You should also be using the `-Wall` flag and pay attention to the warnings it gives you.  Try stepping trough the program that fails first with a debugger and see where it fails.

My bet is that the problem is in your `q_remove` and `q_add` code because that's the code you left out, and because it probably uses arrays.

Comment: gcc -g does not take a number as an argument.  It can take the type of information to create, so for gdb it would be gcc -ggdb.

Comment: @SoapBox: Either it does or it's default debug information format does.  With whatever the newest dwarf symbol format is `-g3` generates debugging symbols with information from the preprocessor as well as from the compiler proper, so gdb can tell you things about macros.